# How to download all Sentinel2 images for a year

Tags: python, sentinel-2, sentinelsat

**Background:** I try to get all available Sentinel-2 Level 1C images for a tile (e.g.T32UPU) in 2016 and 2017. So I applied sentinelsat python package. Almost all images within 2016-2017 have been queried successfully, but there is a gap between 2016-12 and 2017-04.

I first thought this is because ESA didn't publish data for this tile during these months, but then I checked manually on scihub (https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home) and was able to get images from this time period. So it might be an issue with the sentinelsat query.

**Question:** Does anyone else also come across with issues of sentinelsat package and do you have any other better alternatives that would recommend to automatically download this large amount of sentinel2 images?

**Script:**

```
tiles = ['32UPU']

query_kwargs = {
        'platformname': 'Sentinel-2',
        'producttype': 'S2MSI1C',
        'date': ('20160101', '20171231'),
        'relativeorbitnumber': (65)
        }
        
products = OrderedDict()
for tile in tiles:
    kw = query_kwargs.copy()
    kw['tileid'] = tile
    kw['raw'] = f'tileid:{tile} OR filename:*_T{tile}_*'
    pp = api.query(**kw)
    products.update(pp)

#export the result to excel to see all information
gdf = api.to_geodataframe(products)
gdf.to_excel("/Users/path...")
```

Comment: Primary issue that you are encountering is that imagery older than a few months are only available upon request, and you can only request a few images for retrieval. Instead you should possibly consider fetching data from creodias or AWS. For AWS, you can use sentinelhub.aws and for creodias, you can use creodias-finder. Note that retrieval from AWS costs a small bit of money.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen thanks for your reply! For older images there is also a way to request by "api.trigger_offline_retrieval(products_id)". But my issue here is that, I am not downloading all images but just wanna check the dates and the amount of images within a year. So I applied sentinelsat query. But images between 2016-12 and 2017-04 are missing in the list.